# Fixed marker position , move google map and get latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, latitude-longitude

i am using Google Map Sdk for ios.
i want fixed the Marker at 3/4th position of screen on google map.
Now if i move(or scroll) the google map how i will get the location of fixed marker.

same like Ola Cab implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is perfect answer for you. You see me answer...

Here you need to fix the marker position at 3/4 on maps...

Please open this link.

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position { }
```

In this function we can get latitude and longitude on centre of the map.

[How to move marker on the Google Map like Ola app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345449/how-to-move-marker-on-the-google-map-like-ola-app/51266064#51266064)