# How to move marker on the Google Map like Ola app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am working on app the like Ola cabs. When the user drags map the a view transparent view appears with marker moving and when the user stops dragging the we have to centre the gmscamera position same like ola cab app. This the image when the map is not dragged.

[image]

[image: when the user drags the map the screen should be like this]

after dragging I am getting the location using the below code.

```
    - (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {


    latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude;
     longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);


     [self hourelywebsevice:updatedlogintokenstring withlat:latitude withlong:longitude withcoustamerid:updatednamestring];

   // [self hourelywebsevice:@"abc" withlat:latitude withlong:longitude];
    marker.position = center;


}
```

Now my problem is how create second screen.

Comment: Have you implemented Draggable marker like OLA App? I am also working on app like OLA.

Comment: Well this pin is not a marker instead this is added on view it self. And `idleAtCameraPosition` delegate method we fetch the center coordinate by `let coordinate = self.mapView.projection.coordinate(for: pinPointOnView)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use delegates of GMSMapView

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didDragMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```

Comment: Hi Garg,Thanks for quick responce,If user drags map then which method gets called.

Comment: Above given methods will get call, but you can set your coordinates in this method  -(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{        NSLog(@"marker dragged to location: %f,%f", marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude);
}

Comment: the method is not getting called,If see the old app home screen you can easily understand my requirement.

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu have you set the delegates i.e.     mapView_.delegate = self;
    marker_.draggable = YES;

Comment: in the ola app homescreen if just scroll the map then the animation kind of thing begging once if stop scrolling the animation goes the markers point at one place

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu I understand. Let me check

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu have you tried with these delegates                         - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture;            (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position

Comment: Hi minkle, (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture this method is working,how can i show the animation line ola using this method,same line the second image I added,can you please give the complete method.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this kind of things in two apps which are related with live tracking of vahicle.

There are some requirements that I have used:

1. App having Always location usage permission with proper battery usage message.
2. Used Socket connection on both end. Driver & Customer. For that Socket.io is used. Same is configured in Web.
3. Trigged location service at every 2 sec, so that I can handle battery usage.
4. Every 2 sec, send data to socket and socket listener can use that data to show  car on map.
5. Car icon in 90 degree rotate(car indicate to move on right side)

Most important thing is that Driver latitude and longitude should with correct for showing car movement on the map. gmsMarker location consider as old value and newLocation value is current location.

```
let preLoc = CLLocation.init(latitude: self.gmsMarker.position.latitude, longitude: self.gmsMarker.position.longitude)
let curLoc = CLLocation.init(latitude: newLocation.latitude, longitude: newLocation.longitude)
let changeInLocation = preLoc.distance(from: curLoc)
if changeInLocation > 5{
    let degree = self.DegreeBearing(preLoc, curLoc)
    if degree > 5{
        self.gmsMarker.rotation = degree
    }
}
```

Below four function will calculate your travel direction and based on that car will show correct on road with moving.

```
func DegreeBearing(_ A:CLLocation,_ B:CLLocation)-> Double{
    var dlon = self.ToRad(degrees: B.coordinate.longitude - A.coordinate.longitude)
    let dPhi = log(tan(self.ToRad(degrees: B.coordinate.latitude) / 2 + M_PI / 4) / tan(self.ToRad(degrees: A.coordinate.latitude) / 2 + M_PI / 4))
    if  abs(dlon) > M_PI{
        dlon = (dlon > 0) ? (dlon - 2*M_PI) : (2*M_PI + dlon)
    }
    return self.ToBearing(radians: atan2(dlon, dPhi))
}

func ToRad(degrees:Double) -> Double{
    return degrees*(M_PI/180)
}

func ToBearing(radians:Double)-> Double{
    return (ToDegrees(radians: radians) + 360).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
}

func ToDegrees(radians:Double)->Double{
    return radians * 180 / M_PI
}
```

For Customer side, just show marker with whatever data you received from Driver side as `self.gmsMarker.rotation` value.

Comment: @patel thanks for quick responce ,I dont swift language and I dont want to calculate distance,My requirement is when the user scroll the mapview then you should show one transparent view like ola app home screen when you stop scrolling the tanspernt view must go off and markshould place on  mapview same like ola

Comment: Hi @SatheeshkumarNaidu for map move, Google has already that kind of methods in which you can get dragging map events.

    (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
    (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;

Answer (score -1):

```
@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate> {
    GMSMarker *marker2;
}
```

In viewDidLoad

```
marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

// Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                        longitude:longitude
                                                             zoom:18];
// Create GMSMapView
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

// Available map types: kGMSTypeNormal, kGMSTypeSatellite, kGMSTypeHybrid,
// kGMSTypeTerrain, kGMSTypeNone

// Set the mapType to Satellite
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;


mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
marker.map = mapView;

mapView.delegate = self;
```

After that call delegate functions

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture {
//    NSLog(@"willMove");
}

- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
//    NSLog(@"didChangeCameraPosition");

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.

//    NSLog(@"%@", position);
      marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.camera.target.latitude, mapView.camera.target.longitude);
      marker2.map = mapView;
//    marker2.draggable = YES;
      marker2.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];


}
```